# Abstract form of "applying default value"

Tags: haskell, default, default-value, option-type

I want to easily take a value out of a "failable" data type or use a default in the case of failure.

Here's my implementation for `Maybe`:

```
infixr 1 <||>
(<||>) :: Maybe a -> a -> a
(<||>) = flip fromMaybe

pred :: String -> String -> Bool
pred x name = (x ==) <$> name `lookup` myMap <||> False
```

`pred` returns `True` if `name` maps to `x` in `myMap`.

But as is usually the case in Haskell, there is a more abstract way of doing this that I am unaware of. Anyone?

Comment: `maybe False (x ==) $ lookup name myMap`

Comment: Yes, I thought of that too, but I'm looking for more abstractness.

Comment: The problem is that there isn't really a way to abstract away `fromMaybe` because functors, in the general case, don't allow you to extract back a value that has been wrapped. You'll always need a `Maybe`-specific function, which may be `fromMaybe`, `fromJust` or `maybe` depending on how you write it.

Comment: It makes sense that Functor itself cannot provide this, yet I would have imagined another typeclass that might provide it for things like Maybe, Either, etc. It could be implemented for a subset of functors.

Comment: I suppose there haven't been enough use cases where people would want to do it generically. It's always needed with one particular functor, such as you with `Maybe`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Foldable`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-Foldable.html) is probably a reasonable choice from the standard libraries:

```
import Data.Foldable

infixr 1 <||>
(<||>) :: Foldable f => f a -> a -> a

v <||> a =
    case toList v of
        [] -> a
        (x:xs) -> x
```

It does mean you have to decide whether to take the "first" element found or the "last" one though. Also unfortunately it doesn't yet have an `Either` instance, though it's [coming in GHC 7.8/base 4.7](https://github.com/ghc/packages-base/commit/a9a9ce679e0c57437a17824cd6366d085248d217). In the meantime you can define it yourself:

```
instance Foldable (Either a) where
    foldMap _ (Left _) = mempty
    foldMap f (Right y) = f y

    foldr _ z (Left _) = z
    foldr f z (Right y) = f y z
```

Comment: Any reason why it doesn't have that Either instance?

Comment: I was just researching that. Essentially I think it's pending: http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/libraries/2012-July/018248.html, but I'm not quite sure if it's landed or not yet.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with:

```
class Defaultable f where
  infixr 1 <||>
  (<||>) :: f a -> a -> a

instance Defaultable Maybe where
  (<||>) = flip fromMaybe

instance Defaultable (Either a) where
  (Left _)  <||> x = x
  (Right x) <||> _ = x
```

Coupled with `Alternative`, you can string together possible choices with a default at the end.